# Change recorded variables created_at property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to change a database records "created_at" variable after it created?

Comment: I think only through low level database access (i.e. not through the normal AR api). Silly question though: Why on earth do you want to do this? Are you sure you're not trying to mis-use the field?

Comment: 'change' means 'rename'?

Comment: change does not names rename, and i am not misusing the field. The software should hold record about student's non-attendances and i am reaching that data through creation date of the row, it works flawless. Problem is, my customer wants to enter old non-attendance datas too, that's why i am trying to change created_at columns of some data, why create a new column while rails does it for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, since rails 2.3 you can change it like any other column: get the object from the database, set the value for the column, save it.

```
my_model = MyModel.find(42)
my_model.created_at = Date.today
my_model.save
```

Comment: ok than, how can i create a manual date for saving? I mean, i dont want save today but i want to save 10/10/2010?

Comment: @gkaykck You can use `Date.parse('10/10/2010')` to convert strings into Date objects. You might need to watch out for ambiguous situations like '1/2/2010' where it's impossible to tell whether that is January 2nd or February 1st.

Comment: @gkaykck Note that by default the `created_at` field stores down to the resolution of DateTime, not just Date. Ex: `created_at = DateTime.now`

Comment: `my_model.created_at = Date.new(2010,10,10)`

Comment: @gkaykck: Then you can just do `my_model.created_at = "2010-10-10"` (or `my_model.created_at = "10/10/2010"`, though that may not do what you want, depending on which of the 10s you want to be the month and which the day).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a creation date, you may not want to use the default timestamp behavior.

Use a before_save filter, and a custom field 'creation_date'

```
class MyModel
  before_save :set_creation_date

  def set_creation_date
    self.creation_date ||= Date.today
  end
end
```

That way, if you set creation_date yourself, it will get saved to the db with that value, but otherwise Date.today will.

Comment: The suggestion above which suggests using `before_filter` is incorrect. `before_filter` is a controller method rather than one which would be used in a model. You may require `before_save|create|update` in models.